# A group that needs to be proven by definition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let X be a set and let $P(X)$ denote the set of all subsets of X, that is $P(X)=  
> \{A|A\subseteq X\}$. given $A,B\in P(X),$ define $A \triangle B:=(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$.
>
> Prove that $(P(X), \triangle)$ is a group.

Using the definition of a group I assume I have to show that there exist an associativity, identity, and inverse.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. You have to show that this is an associative binary operation with identity and inverse. (It's also commutative).

From what I can tell, that was your question.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint.*

First figure out the identity, then figure out the inverses.

Save associativity for last- it is just tedious definition chasing.